# How can I jump to line in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Does anyone know of a shortcut for jumping to a specific line (given a #) in Sublime Text?

Ex: I run code and get an error at line 5765. I want to be able to jump quickly in Sublime Text to line 5765, without scrolling.

Answer (score 175):

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Linux:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

or

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>

Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>

Then type the line number. It will automatically find it for you and if it requires scrolling to get to - it will snap your view to the line number level.

Comment: If you're already in the habit of navigating between project files with the "Goto Anything" command ( Ctrl+P / Cmd + P), you can also use that- just type a colon, and then the line number.

Comment: It's Control+ G on Mac

Answer (score 53):

Rather than `Control+G`, if you're used to using `CMD+P` or `CMD+T`, you can just type `:`

---

Also useful:

- `CMD+R` go to function in current file
- `CMD+Shift+R` find function in any file (`CMD+,` "binary_file_patterns" ignore node_modules)
- `CMD+Option+Down` jump to function definition in another file (from cursor word)
- `CMD+D` / `CMD+U` jump & accumulate next word occurrence & populate search query / (undo). from cursor becomes an exact match (case and word boundary) vs from selection is a partial match (ignore case and word boundary). `D` and `U` also work in less [bash / zshell pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix))  to scroll down / up half pages
- `CMD+G` / `CMD+Shift+G` jump or "go" to next / previous search query (`CMD+D` amazing with this)
- `CMD+{` / `CMD+}` focuses left / right tab (same in terminals, browser, kapeli dash, etc.)
- `CMD+[` / `CMD+]` shift line left / right (chrome forward / backward nav, devtools changes panel)
- `CMD+Control+Up` / `CMD+Control+Down` shift line up / down
- `CMD+K->(some number)` fold to  indentation
- `CMD+K->J` unfold all
- `CMD+Option+[` / `CMD+Option+]` fold / unfold current line's children
- `CMD+,` is preferences in most all Mac applications

Comment: For shift line in Windows, it's `ctrl` + `shift` + `up`/`down`.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by @maxTuzz, I use **Ubuntu 16.06** and Sublime regularly,
 this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then Pressing <kbd>:</kbd> and Starting typing the Line Number you want to Navigate.

**Or**

Directly we can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> Starting typing the Line Number you want to Navigate.

Answer (score 5):

In My Mac， Performance>>Key Bindings add：

```
//line duplicate & delete
{ "keys": ["super+y"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"} },
{ "keys": ["super+d"], "command": "duplicate_line" },

//replace
{ "keys": ["super+r"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "replace", "reverse": false} },

//goto
{ "keys": ["super+l"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": ":"} },
{ "keys": ["super+g"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": "@"} },

//upper or lower
{ "keys": ["super+shift+u"], "command": "swap_case" },

//sidebar toggle
{ "keys": ["super+shift+t"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" },
```

Answer (score 3):

base is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and a then type <kbd>:</kbd> and then write the line that you want to go , **BUT** there is a shortcut for this : 
Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> , and it does the same steps for you!

Answer (score 0):

on your keyboard click the:

```
command + p
```

then type `:` on your keyboard follow by the line number, *example* `374`

```
:374
```

then click the `enter` key on your keyboard to jump to the desired line number